# TOMCAT : unable to create new native thread. Неоправданное потребление ОЗУ

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat

WEB-сервер tomcat 9.0 работает 2-3 минуты и падает. При этом появляется ошибка OutOfMemoryError и использовано абсолютно вся отведенная оперативная память для приложения. На сервер обращаюсь только я - один клиент. Информация для передачи не больше 100кб за один запрос.

Работает сервер на Windows 7 x32.

На сервере работает 4 сервлета (doGet), которые с помощью объекта самописного класса собирают информацию об устройстве и передают ее в .JSP.

1. В 'catalina.propirties' прописывал'org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false';
2. Обнулял переменные после передачи данных в JSP. Обнулял переменные после использования в самом JSP;
3. Вызывал System.gc() для принудительной очистки мусора;
4. В 'web.xml' добавлял параметр в сервлеты: 'enablePool = false';
5. 'В context.xml' добавлял 'cachingAllowed="false" '

Ничего из этого не исправило проблемы.

Профилер указывает на большое кол-во Strin и Char элементов, но все элементы должны после использования на сервере обнулены.

Где искать проблему?

Comment: БД используете в приложении? Может быть утечка по JDBC пулу. Может быть зацикливание где-то в самой логике приложений(к примеру рекурсионный вызов функции)

Comment: БД не использую. Использую класс, который обращается по SNMP к сетевому оборудованию, получаем массив данных, передаем в JSP. Циклов нет, кроме foreach в самом JSP. Рост затраченной ОЗУ происходит единожды за один запрос, потом он ее просто не очищает. Так до следующего запроса

Comment: Попробуйте в `JSP` добавить тег `<%@page session="false"%>` в самом верху(Был случай, когда у нас не умирали сессии на страницах и было переполнение)

Comment: Не помогло ни на йоту. Можете посоветовать какой - либо инструмент для выявления проблемы?

Comment: К сожалению ничего не приходит на ум. Ещё вариант: вы случайно какой-то альтернативный GC не используете в своём TC? В параметрах запуска? К примеру -XX:+UseG1GC? И попробуйте запуститься на другом ТС. К примеру на 8

Comment: А сколько именно памяти используется, каков масштаб проблемы? Утечка скорее всего в вашем коде. Причин может быть множество. Как вариант диагностики: запустите `jvisualvm`, там сделайте heap dump, далее там есть возможность найти N самых больших объектов. Плюс в том, что там можно посмотреть, кто ссылается на объект и на кого объект ссылается, т.е. можно найти откуда ноги растут.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. jvisualvm мне помог в анализе

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы были в моем коде.  В классе, который обращался по SNMP к сетевому оборудованию и собирал информацию. При этом открывался Listner (UDP), который не закрывался сборщиком мусора.

В класс добавил функцию закрытия Listner'a  - утечка памяти исключена.